# Why I have to go to run configuration in Eclipse, everytime?

Tags: java, eclipse

I wrote two java projects which are purely independent.
When I run the first project "aa", automatically a "Run Configurations" window appeared, and I chose "cc" (cc.java) under Java Application tab.

The app run.

but when I made another java project "dd" and wrote code in its class "ff", The run button showed the output of cc.java in console.

I had to go to "Run Configurations", and select "ff" (ff.java) under Java Application tab.

Why I have to to do this everytime?
What if I have multiple classes under one project?
Is there anyway to run a project by simply clicking run button?

Regards,
BAQAR RAZA MANGRANI
Struggling programmer.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, if you have several classes including a `main` method in eclipse, as soon as you run them once, they appear as shortcuts when expanding the run button(or debug). Just click on the small arrow next to the start button and select the file you want to run.